# Sorting list of RBG triplets

Tags: python, list, sorting, colors, rgb

I've been making a code for finding the dominant colors from an image.
I have a problem when I am printing the result (the result is in the form of a list with RGB triplets; [(244, 181, 28), (230, 146, 38)]).

I want the list to show the RGB-triplet with the most dominant color first but the result always gets printed out with the colors in random order.
Can anyone help me sort this list so I can have the most dominant first and second most and so on?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
class Cluster(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.pixels = []
    self.centroid = None


def addPoint(self, pixel):
    self.pixels.append(pixel)


def setNewCentroid(self):
    R = [colour[0] for colour in self.pixels]
    G = [colour[1] for colour in self.pixels]
    B = [colour[2] for colour in self.pixels]

    R = sum(R) / len(R)
    G = sum(G) / len(G)
    B = sum(B) / len(B)

    self.centroid = (R, G, B)
    self.pixels = []        
    return self.centroid


class Kmeans(object):
    def __init__(self, k=2, max_iterations=5, min_distance=2.0, size=200):
    self.k = k
    self.max_iterations = max_iterations
    self.min_distance = min_distance
    self.size = (size, size)


def run(self, image):
    self.image = image
    self.image.thumbnail(self.size)
    self.pixels = numpy.array(image.getdata(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

    self.clusters = [None for i in range(self.k)]
    self.oldClusters = None

    randomPixels = random.sample(self.pixels, self.k)

    for idx in range(self.k):
        self.clusters[idx] = Cluster()
        self.clusters[idx].centroid = randomPixels[idx]

    iterations = 0
    while self.shouldExit(iterations) is False:

        self.oldClusters = [cluster.centroid for cluster in self.clusters]
        print iterations

        for pixel in self.pixels:
            self.assignClusters(pixel)

        for cluster in self.clusters:
            print len(cluster.pixels)
            cluster.setNewCentroid()

        iterations += 1
    return [cluster.centroid for cluster in self.clusters]


def assignClusters(self, pixel):
    shortest = float('Inf')
    for cluster in self.clusters:
        distance = self.calcDistance(cluster.centroid, pixel)
        if distance < shortest:
            shortest = distance
            nearest = cluster

    nearest.addPoint(pixel)


def calcDistance(self, a, b):
    result = numpy.sqrt(sum((a - b) ** 2))
    return result


def shouldExit(self, iterations):
    if self.oldClusters is None:
        return False

    for idx in range(self.k):
        dist = self.calcDistance(
            numpy.array(self.clusters[idx].centroid),
            numpy.array(self.oldClusters[idx])
        )
        if dist < self.min_distance:
            return True

    if iterations <= self.max_iterations:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: It would help me if you could add a sample image and some code that uses your classes to load that image and produce the incorrect result. Having an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is really helpful. When editing the question, also please fix the indentation (the classes' functions need to be indented once more).